# PHP Encode in IOS with NSUTF8StringEncoding Decode in

Tags: php, iphone

I am creating a POST with data encoded to UTF-8 (`NSUTF8StringEncoding`). My source string is
 `06d218681ca46c42218baf14af1c16bd7c660740` and results in data of `34343462 36616436 65333864 32636566 65663261 33303831 32313263 66383334 33386162 30306236`.

I want to decode it in PHP.

In iOS my code is:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"access_token\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[[AppManager sharedManager] Access_token] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uid\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[[AppManager sharedManager] loggedInUserId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: `NSUTF8StringEncoding` isn't a function. Show the code you're using.

Comment: @Wain -yes one minute

Comment: @iDev i have no idea where to start which method is use for this decodeing, i apply base64_decode()

Answer (score 0):

if you want 64bitdecoding try this

```
  NSData *resultData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:yourDecodeData options:0];
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] resultData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are POSTing the content based on the code you show. This really has nothing to do with iOS (hence my edits to your question).

In PHP, you need to [handle the POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) that is received.

You are sending `access_token` and `uid`, so try `echo`ing in your PHP (which returns the data to the client, so your `NSURLConnection` should receive the response):

```
<?php
    echo 'Received: ' . $_POST["access_token"]) . ' and: ' . $_POST["uid"]);
?>
```